# Spring Send Blob to Stored Procedure

Tags: java, spring, stored-procedures, websphere, blob

I'm trying to send a Blob to a stored procedure without success.
First of all, I had some limitations, i.e. I cannot use a prepared statement.

Secondly, I'm sure that the stored procedure works, because I've tried
it with success calling manually the procedure and with prepared statement.

If I execute this all works correctly:

```
PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("call t1000_adm.Mandamail.manda_mail(?)");
file = new File(request.getPathAllegato());
InputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
ps.setBinaryStream(1, fis, (int)file.length());
ps.execute();
```

But I'm forced to use Spring MVC with WebSphere application server and I cannot use directly a prepared statement.
I have to use a javax.sql.DataSource and org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.MapSqlParameterSource.

This is what I have to do:

```
MapSqlParameterSource paramSource = new MapSqlParameterSource();
paramSource.addValue(BLOB_NAME, blob);
CustomStoredProcedure proc = new CustomStoredProcedure( dataSource, storedProcedure); 
proc.execute(paramSource);
```

In CustomStoredProcedure, which extends org.springframework.jdbc.object.StoredProcedure, I have to associate to BLOB_NAME an Oracle Data Type, in this way:

```
public CustomStoredProcedure(DataSource dataSource, String sprocName) {
    super(dataSource, sprocName);
    declareParameter(new SqlParameter(BLOB_NAME, OracleTypes.BLOB));
    compile();
}
```

Now, here's the problems:

1. If I try to create the blob object with dataSource.getConnection().createBlob() I receive the error:

> java.sql.SQLFeatureNotSupportedException: DSRA1300E: Function not implemented: Connection.createBlob

(the description may be incorrect but I have the localized version and I translated it in English).

2. If I try to create the blob object with BLOB.createTemporary I receive the error

> java.lang.ClassCastException: com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.jdbc.WSJdbcConnection incompatible with oracle.jdbc.OracleConnection

3. If I use

   com.ibm.websphere.rsadapter.WSCallHelper.getNativeConnection( dataSource.getConnection)

I receive the compiling error (only with Ant, with Eclipse I have no problem):

> error: package com.ibm.websphere.rsadapter not exists
> [javac] import com.ibm.websphere.rsadapter.WSCallHelper

(as before, I translated the error)

4. If I ignore the Ant compiling error and use it anyway I receive the execution error:

> [31/05/17 9.52.50:414 CEST] 0000007f SystemErr     R org.springframework.jdbc.UncategorizedSQLException: CallableStatementCallback; uncategorized SQLException for SQL [{call MANDAMAIL.MANDA_MAIL(?)}]; SQL state [99999]; error code [22922]; ORA-22922: valore LOB non esistente
> ORA-06512: a "SYS.DBMS_LOB", line 837
> ORA-06512: a "T1000_ADM.MANDAMAIL", line 190
> ORA-06512: a line 1
> ; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: ORA-22922: valore LOB non esistente
> ORA-06512: a "SYS.DBMS_LOB", line 837
> ORA-06512: a "T1000_ADM.MANDAMAIL", line 190
> ORA-06512: a line 1
>
> [31/05/17 9.52.50:415 CEST] 0000007f SystemErr     R   at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:83)
> [31/05/17 9.52.50:415 CEST] 0000007f SystemErr     R    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:80)
> [31/05/17 9.52.50:416 CEST] 0000007f SystemErr     R    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:80)
> [31/05/17 9.52.50:416 CEST] 0000007f SystemErr     R    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:1030)
> [31/05/17 9.52.50:416 CEST] 0000007f SystemErr     R    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.call(JdbcTemplate.java:1064)
> [31/05/17 9.52.50:417 CEST] 0000007f SystemErr     R    at org.springframework.jdbc.object.StoredProcedure.execute(StoredProcedure.java:144)
> [31/05/17 9.52.50:417 CEST] 0000007f SystemErr     R    at com.bpvn.vieniconnoi.dao.MandaMailStoredProcedure.execute(MandaMailStoredProcedure.java:42)...

The line 190 of the procedure is the first occurrance of DBMS_LOB.
This is the stored procedure (in Java code I've removed other params for simplicity).

```
PROCEDURE manda_mail(   destinatario          IN VARCHAR2,
                        cc                    IN VARCHAR2,
                        mittente              IN VARCHAR2,
                        oggetto               IN VARCHAR2,
                        corpo                 IN VARCHAR2 DEFAULT NULL,
                        nomeAllegato          IN VARCHAR2 DEFAULT NULL,
                        allegato              IN BLOB DEFAULT NULL)
AS
  l_mail_conn   UTL_SMTP.connection;
  l_boundary    VARCHAR2(50) := '----=*#abc1234321cba#*=';
  l_step        PLS_INTEGER  := 12000; -- make sure you set a multiple of 3 not higher than 24573
  v_mime VARCHAR2(50) := 'application/pdf';
BEGIN
  l_mail_conn := UTL_SMTP.open_connection(C_SMTP_SERVER, 25);
  UTL_SMTP.helo(l_mail_conn, C_SMTP_SERVER);
  UTL_SMTP.mail(l_mail_conn, mittente);
  UTL_SMTP.rcpt(l_mail_conn, destinatario);

  UTL_SMTP.open_data(l_mail_conn);
  
  UTL_SMTP.write_data(l_mail_conn, 'Date: ' || TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') || UTL_TCP.crlf);
  UTL_SMTP.write_data(l_mail_conn, 'To: ' || destinatario || UTL_TCP.crlf);
  UTL_SMTP.write_data(l_mail_conn, 'From: ' || mittente || UTL_TCP.crlf);
  UTL_SMTP.write_data(l_mail_conn, 'Subject: ' || oggetto || UTL_TCP.crlf);
  UTL_SMTP.write_data(l_mail_conn, 'Reply-To: ' || mittente || UTL_TCP.crlf);
  UTL_SMTP.write_data(l_mail_conn, 'MIME-Version: 1.0' || UTL_TCP.crlf);
  UTL_SMTP.write_data(l_mail_conn, 'Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="' || l_boundary || '"' || UTL_TCP.crlf || UTL_TCP.crlf);
  
  IF corpo IS NOT NULL THEN
    UTL_SMTP.write_data(l_mail_conn, '--' || l_boundary || UTL_TCP.crlf);
    UTL_SMTP.write_data(l_mail_conn, 'Content-Type: text/plain; charset="iso-8859-1"' || UTL_TCP.crlf || UTL_TCP.crlf);

    UTL_SMTP.write_data(l_mail_conn, corpo);
    UTL_SMTP.write_data(l_mail_conn, UTL_TCP.crlf || UTL_TCP.crlf);
  END IF;

  IF nomeAllegato IS NOT NULL THEN
    UTL_SMTP.write_data(l_mail_conn, '--' || l_boundary || UTL_TCP.crlf);
    UTL_SMTP.write_data(l_mail_conn, 'Content-Type: ' || v_mime || '; name="' || nomeAllegato || '"' || UTL_TCP.crlf);
    UTL_SMTP.write_data(l_mail_conn, 'Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64' || UTL_TCP.crlf);
    UTL_SMTP.write_data(l_mail_conn, 'Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' || nomeAllegato || '"' || UTL_TCP.crlf || UTL_TCP.crlf);

    FOR i IN 0 .. TRUNC((DBMS_LOB.getlength(allegato) - 1 )/l_step) LOOP
      UTL_SMTP.write_data(l_mail_conn, UTL_RAW.cast_to_varchar2(UTL_ENCODE.base64_encode(DBMS_LOB.substr(allegato, l_step, i * l_step + 1))));
    END LOOP;

    UTL_SMTP.write_data(l_mail_conn, UTL_TCP.crlf || UTL_TCP.crlf);
  END IF;
  
  UTL_SMTP.write_data(l_mail_conn, '--' || l_boundary || '--' || UTL_TCP.crlf);
  UTL_SMTP.close_data(l_mail_conn);

  UTL_SMTP.quit(l_mail_conn);
END;
```

To get this I've used the code written before creating the blob object in this way:

```
BLOB blob = BLOB.createTemporary(WSCallHelper.getNativeConnection(dataSource.getConnection()), false, BLOB.DURATION_SESSION);
FileInputStream is = new FileInputStream(filePath);
byte[] buffer = new byte[30000000];
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

int bytesRead;
while ((bytesRead = is.read(buffer)) != -1) {
    baos.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
}

blob.setBytes(1, baos.toByteArray());
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem solved:
I do not need to use Blob object: I can use simple byte[] on Java-side, put it in paramSource and bind that array with OracleTypes.BINARY.
That works.